# How to debug in meteor.js

Tags: debugging, meteor

I know there is a debug option where you can start meteor like this:

```
meteor debug
```

It then starts the node debugger. However, if I were to set a break point through the node inspector interface, the program just won't stop at the break point. So instead, I would have to put a "debugger;" statement in the source code before the line I want to break. It works for the first time, but on the second time after I made some change to the source code, the program just hangs there. I would have to

```
killall -9 node
```

to exit meteor, rerun meteor debug, and wait for another 2 minutes for meteor to cold start again. It's unusable!

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the newest 1.4.1.1 version. It didn't work. Is it a known bug, or was I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Gladly, this problem has now been fixed in version 1.4.2.